# How does create a new page works? [Web architecture]

Tags: php, html, database, web, directory

How does create a new page works? Let's say a website that allow users to create a post, at this point I'll be thinking of a link like this

> example.com/post/randomised123

Now here's my curiosity, does it happen behind the server directory too like any popular sites such as YouTube and Facebook or eBay? Meaning the popular sites do contain millions and millions folders/pages?
What about an user profile? Many sites have its own profile link. For example:

> example.com/profile/superman1998

Which is going to be a directory that contains a folder name called **superman1998** inside the profile folder? Are they just visually displayed but nothing is actually in the folder directory but how does it works? Sorry for my English... I'm not very good at it.

Comment: short answer the site takes the url and generates a file on the fly probably from templates and data stored in a database. Long answer: off topic for stackoverflow

Comment: It may also use url rewriting via a `.htaccess` (or web.config) file

Comment: It may be a little off topic, or theoretical, but for people who are learning how to make websites  it is something you have to understand in order to know how things work.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen you could say turning on a computer is also something you have to understand, but it still a lot off topic here.

Comment: @Dagon But this is not a broad question! It does not even come close. It may be a very basic question, but it is narrowed down and *very* relevant to people who haven't yet learned how URL paths work.

Comment: well i guess its a matter of opinion, you can write books on this very question.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at this URL:

```
http://www.google.com/some/path?one=1&two=2#pageElement
```

This contains several things:

- `http://` is the protocol
- `www.google.com` is the domain name
- `/some/path` is the path
- `?one=1&two=2` is the query string
- `#pageElement` is the fragment

(URLs can contain more than that, but you can learn that when you get to it.)

The **path** of a URL may be an actual physical location on the server (a folder or a file within a folder), but it can also just be a label that the server parses and then does with as it sees fit.

When the path is not a folder or a file it is just a string that the server uses. For example, a path like `/user/123/profile` may just be a label that the server breaks down into 3 parts:

1. module = `user`
2. user id = `123`
3. page = `profile`

The server will then look for the `user` module on its system, load the user that has the ID `123` and then show that user's `profile` page.

To sum up: A path can be an actual folder or file on the server, but the server can also grab that path and break it up into parts, in order to find out what to do with it.